# How to get data from html with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get text the same as picture with Python.
Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Comment: Try with `selenium` and `beautifulsoup` and post some code for us so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try tools like [html2text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text) and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

Answer (score 0):

I know that using regex in html is probably not the best way but you can do :

```
import re

code_search = re.search('>\n?" Security code: "\n?<[^<>]+>\n?(\d*)\n?<', html)
if code_search:
    print(code_search.group(1))
```